# Howto navigate in Angular 2 when using ngrx store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

I'm using ngrx store (4.x) together with Angular 4. I use effects to make CRUD operations on the backend, like the example below which adds a Task on the backend API.

**Effect:**

```
  @Effect()
  addTask: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(LeadAction.ADD_TASK)
    .map((action: LeadAction.AddTaskAction) => action.payload)
    .switchMap((task: TaskViewModel) => {
      return this.leadApi.leadAddTask(task.LeadId, task)
        .map((taskResult: TaskViewModel) => {
          return new LeadAction.AddTaskSuccessAction(taskResult);
        })
        .catch((e: any) => of(new LeadAction.AddTaskFailureAction(e)));
    });
```

**TaskEditComponent :**

```
  onSave(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(new AddTaskAction(this.task));

    // **** NAVIGATE TO PAGE TaskListComponent or OverviewComponent ON SUCCESS
    // OR
    // **** NAVGIATE TO PAGE Y ON ERROR
  }
```

Question: In my component I need to navigate to different pages and I struggle now where to put this logic?

Especially when I think about following scenarios, where the TaskEditComponent is 'called' by different Components:

*Should navigate back to TaskListComponent:*

OverviewComponent->TaskListComponent->TaskEditComponent back to List

*Should navigate back to OverviewComponent:*

OverviewComponent->TaskEditComponent

Comment: it too broad depends on your secenario, , you can check the present store atate after dispatch and then navigate i guess

Comment: @RahulSingh some general patterns or advices woul help.

Comment: I would suggest after dispatching the action get hold of the present value of store and if it holds the correct value then navigate or else dont . this is what should be the idea way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `ngrx`, it makes sense to let your store handle the router state as well, preserving the *redux* paradigm. Then you would simply dispatch a router action in the effect in reaction to your success actions.

This has the added benefit of being able to '[time travel](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2016/01/25/angular2-time-travel-with-redux.html)' the routes as well as the rest of the app state.

<s>Fortunately, there is already an [implementation of router-store integration](https://github.com/ngrx/router-store) ready to be used.</s>

---

You could do something like this (just a guideline, enhance to your needs):

app.module

```
import { StoreRouterConnectingModule, routerReducer } from '@ngrx/router-store';
import { App } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ routerReducer: routerReducer }),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      // ...
      { path: 'task-list', component: TaskListComponent },
      { path: 'error-page', component: ErrorPageComponent }
    ]),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [App]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

task.effects

```
import { go } from '@ngrx/router-store';

@Effect()
addTask: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(LeadAction.ADD_TASK_SUCCESS)
  .map((action: LeadAction.AddTaskSuccessAction) => action.payload)
  .map((payload: any) => go('/task-list')); // use payload to construct route options

@Effect()
addTask: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
  .ofType(LeadAction.ADD_TASK_FAILURE)
  .mapTo(go('/error-page'));
```

---

## Update using NGRX v8+ with latest features:

**AppModule**:

```
import { StoreRouterConnectingModule, routerReducer } from '@ngrx/router-store';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    StoreModule.forRoot({ routerReducer }),
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      // ...
      { path: 'task-list', component: TaskListComponent },
      { path: 'error-page', component: ErrorPageComponent }
    ]),
    StoreRouterConnectingModule.forRoot(),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**TaskEffects**:

```
@Injectable()
export class TaskEffects {
  readonly addTaskSuccess$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(LeadAction.ADD_TASK_SUCCESS),
      tap(() => this.router.navigate(['task-list'])),
    ),
    { dispatch: false },
  );
  readonly addTaskFailure$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(LeadAction.ADD_TASK_FAILURE),
      tap(() => this.router.navigate(['error-page'])),
    ),
    { dispatch: false },
  );

  constructor(
    private readonly actions$: Actions,
    private readonly router: Router,
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: Heehaw, thx for the hint. I checked for ngrx version 4.x this Readme https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/router-store/README.md but to be honest, I have no idea what do to.

Comment: You can try explorin [their sample app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/example-app/README.md). The router module is used there, as well as other useful stuff.

Comment: [The GitHub readme file](https://github.com/ngrx/router-store/blob/master/README.md) explains the setup and usage step-by-step.

Comment: Heehaaw, your solution is for ngrx-router-store < 4.x, they changed a lot in version 4 - but you guided me in the right direction - thx a lot for your help. :-)

Comment: Oh, OK, I didn't check that :-). I'm glad I could help!

Comment: You can't call `subscribe` on `@Effect()` as that would yield a subscription and not an observable. I can't comment on anything else as I'm new to ngrx. +1 for your profile image.

Comment: there's no go within router-store as of v4, so you'll need to call router.navigate from the effect via do.

Comment: I'd rather see this answer updated with `tap` and `{ dispatch: false }`.